# Semantic UI menu - disappearing on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I have a semantic-UI lefside menu that I want to be persistent. I am trying to make 2 states -  a wide one with type for each item, and a compact one with an image for each item.
Currently there are a few issues that I am totally stumped on!

1) Why does the menu completely go away on click?

2) How can I make the page NOT do dim?

3) Can the page collapse in width instead of getting pushed to the right?

4) is it possible to have two menu states, as described, and toggle between them on click?

Thank you very much!
My site is here: http://itp.evejweinberg.com/left/

And my html:

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="semantic/semantic.min.css">

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,800" rel="stylesheet">


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

          <!-- my json of content -->
          <script type="text/javascript" src="list.js"></script>
          <!-- jQuery to build that content -->
          <script type="text/javascript" src="buildScene.js"></script>

        <script src="semantic/semantic.min.js"></script>



      </head>
<!--//do I need this class? -->
      <body class="pushable">



    <!-- semantic says to put everything in pusher -->
    <div class="pusher">


      <div class="all">

          <div id="main"></div>

          <div class="title-holder">
            <div class="animatedDiv"></div>
          </div>



            <div class='container'>
                <div class='header'></div>
                <div class="all-books"></div>
            </div>
      </div>

      </div>


    <!-- menu -->
    <div class="ui vertical left labeled menu fixed small sidebar">
        <div class="header link item" onclick="scrollTo(captology)">Intro</div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="header link item">Emotions</div>
        <div class="menu">
          <a class="item link" onclick="scrollTo(hope)">Hope</a>
          <a class="item link" onclick="scrollTo(anxiety)">Anxiety</a>
          <a class="item link" onclick="scrollTo(fear)">Fear</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="header link item">Psychology</div>
        <div class="menu">
          <a class="item link" onclick="scrollTo(transparency)">Transparency</a>
          <a class="item link" onclick="scrollTo(loss)">Loss Aversion</a>
          <a class="item link" onclick="scrollTo(dark)">Dark Patterns</a>
          <a class="item link" onclick="scrollTo(social)">Social Pressure</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="header link" onclick="scrollTo(fogg)">Fogg</div>
        <div class="menu">
          <a class="item link" onclick="scrollTo(motivation)">Motivation</a>
          <a class="item link" onclick="scrollTo(ability)">Ability</a>
          <a class="item link" onclick="scrollTo(trigger)">Trigger</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="header link" onclick="scrollTo(flow)">Flow</div>
        <div class="menu">
          <a class="item link" onclick="scrollTo(chunking)">Chunking</a>
          <!-- <a class="item">FAQs</a> -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="header">Ethics</div>
        <div class="menu">
          <div class="nav-rect" id="e"></div>
          <div class="nav-rect" id="e"></div>
          <div class="nav-rect" id="e"></div>
          <div class="nav-rect" id="e"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="header link" onclick="scrollTo(sources)">Sources</div>

      </div>
        <div class="header">About</div>
        <div class="ui category search item">
          <div class="ui transparent icon input">
            <input class="prompt" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
            <i class="search link icon"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="results"></div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>








        <script type="text/javascript" src="content.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/intro.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/hope.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lossAversion.js"></script>



        <script type="text/javascript">

        $('.sidebar').sidebar('show');

      //   $('.sidebar')
      // .visibility({
      //   type   : 'fixed',
      //   offset : 45 // give some space from top of screen
      // });

        // $('.menu').click(function(){
        //   $('.ui.labeled.icon.sidebar').sidebar('toggle');
        //
        // })

        // $('.ui.sidebar').click(function(){
        //   sidebar('toggle');
        // })


        </script>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved! Semantic-UI was dynamically adding to my html on build. I removed the class 'sidebar' and all pusher and dimmer css went away. That solves #1 and #2. For the rest, i'm just going to go back to jQuery animations to slide the left nav to the left and collapse it's width. Thx All!